Troubleshooting failed update Windows 10 version 22H2
Since several weeks the update mentioned above fails on my Laptop (Lenovo Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4558U CPU, 64-bit, x64 based, built in 2018, so a bit old).
During this time the update remained stuck at 61% for a long time before failing with varying error codes. I already tried (without success) the following options:
1. Run windows update troubleshooter
No problem identified
2. Remove possibly conflicting conexant drivers
According to this link, uninstalling Conexant audio drivers (including hidden ones) should help.
So, I  uninstalled Conexant audio drivers and followed instructions provided here (case 1])
Next attempt still stuck at 61% before failing with error 0xc1900104
Note: during the update, even without rebooting, my system reinstalls the conexant drivers, so I was never able to really try this fix. Is it possible to temporarily prevent the system from reinstalling this driver?
3. Tackle error 0xc1900104
I then sought for help on solving the reported problem and followed the steps suggested in this link, which are quite similar to suggestions I found here on superuser:
I paste below the steps


Open the command prompt as administrator on your computer
Type each command below and press enter after each command

net stop wuauserv net stop bits net stop cryptsvc net stop
trustedinstaller
You may need to run the command more than ones until you see the
message that the service has stopped successfully. (Note: Make sure
that all those command will stop the services otherwise the next
command will not work)

Type the following commands to clear the Windows Update cache to allow Windows 10 re-download the updates, instead of using the files
already downloaded on your system that might be damaged

ren %systemroot%\softwaredistribution softwaredistribution.old ren
%systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.old
(Note: Make sure that those folders will be renamed by running those
command)

Restart the update services on the computer. On the same command prompt (running as administrator), type each command below and press
enter after each command

net start wuauserv net start bits net start cryptsvc net start
trustedinstaller net start appidsvc
Please disable any 3rd party security software that you have to ensure
that those applications is not blocking the installation of updates.

As a result, installation was stuck at 61% for a coupe of days and then returned error 0xc1900104
At this point, I am a bit stuck. Any suggestions? Maybe a clean boot as suggested here?
Edit
As required by Ramhound I add here a link to the log of SetupDiag. I link here to all the generated files (including a zipped folder). While the main log (setupdiag.log) doesn't reveal any problem in the zip folder, I noticed that the last operation listed in the file setupact.log in the zipped folder is related to conexant drivers.
In addition, Ramhound is right, my system is not trying to update TO 22H2, but it is trying to install additional updates to it.

It also just updated the .NET framework, and waiting to reboot, according to the screenshot. Sorry for the Italian and sorry for the screenshot. I will be happy to provide further logs.
I rebooted as suggested by the system. I am now stuck at the 61% installation. Waiting for the next error message...

Provide the log from Setup Diag

Thanks, edited question and added link to all log files of SetupDiag.

It appears you already have Windows 10 22H2 installed.  HostOSVersion = 10.0.19045.  Which begs the question, what update is failing, since it's obviously not the update to Windows 10 22H2

I think you are right... re-updated the question, and pondering if rebooting now or not. But maybe the culprit is KB5037724

yes, I had to perform a clean install i followed this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/ Windows insider link
download the latest preview 216100.21 this is at the top about 3rd down
insider preview 2
be carefull not to install the ones above as these are dev updates and such for different things like developer updates to 23h2, then I had to mount the image using Rufus (google rufus mounting tool), I then did a full clean install after deleted all drive contents and partitions, this took about 20 minutes, after that I was successfully running windows (after I ran windows update) since then I have installed all drivers and games successfully , I have found one or two problems, Windows is now a lot more sensistive to overclocking and tools of the like, for instance it took me a while to discover my bios PBO undervolt for my amd cpu was now too much, after running for nearly a year on previous windows at -30 I have had to do Dism restore health a few times and now it will run at -25, then I downloaded the nvidia app beta that auto overclocks your card, again ran into problems after running that and rebooting, msi afterburner is fine.
im now back working and gaming, with better performance, on my computer. thanks for the advice.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Here is as I finally solved the issue.

Perform a clean boot following the instruction in this link

Soon after rebooting, uninstall conexant drivers as I specified in step 2 of my question, and following this link.


VERY IMPORTANT: windows will automatically reinstall the conexant drivers so, either you disable the automatic reinstall, or if you are not able (like me!), simply keep an eye on the devices, and as soon as the drivers are reinstalled, you uninstall them. I know it's a dumb way, but it worked.
